# XMPP Server-to-server SASL handshake

Tags: xmpp

I am trying to connect a server to a XMPP server, using the MD5 Digest SASL handshake. But the XMPP server always rejects my response to the challenge. The RFC says the response should look like:

```
username="example.org",realm="somerealm",\
nonce="OA6MG9tEQGm2hh",cnonce="OA6MHXh6VqTrRk",\
nc=00000001,qop=auth,digest-uri="xmpp/example.org",\
response=d388dad90d4bbd760a152321f2143af7,charset=utf-8
```

But the value of ***response*** (which I have correctly generated based on the inputs) relies on the username and password. For server-to-server communication, which username and password should it be using? The ***example.org*** username in the spec doesnt seem right..

Answer (score 0):

You've probably solved this by now, but this is for the record. See RFC3920, section 6.1, item 6: "If provision of a 'simple username' is supported by the selected SASL mechanism (e.g., this is supported by the DIGEST-MD5 and CRAM-MD5 mechanisms but not by the EXTERNAL and GSSAPI mechanisms), during authentication the initiating entity SHOULD provide as the simple username its sending domain (IP address or fully qualified domain name as contained in a domain identifier) in the case of server-to-server communications or its registered account name (user or node name as contained in an XMPP node identifier) in the case of client-to-server communications."

At least, that conditionally takes care of the username. The password I couldn't even guess at. I'm writing a client-to-server script, so I'll be using my own gmail username and password, but that isn't likely to work for server-to-server.